# How would I direct local(127.0.0.1) MySQL traffic to an external SQL server?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, mysql

Basically, I have two EC2 instances on Amazon Web Services. They are both running Ubuntu 11.10 x64. They both have a private and a public (Elastic) IP addresses. I'm having trouble setting up iptables to forward SQL data properly.

I would like it so that if I connect to "127.0.0.1:3306" on Server A (which does not have an SQL server installed), it will forward to `<private ip>:3306` (aka Server B -- which does have an SQL server installed).

I'm able to access each server (from the other) using the associated private ip's. I'd like to keep the forwarding private as well without having to use a public IP.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why does it need to connect to `localhost`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't want to make the actual MySQL server on Server B open to remote connections (from the internet). However, I still want to be able to access it from Server A, internally.

Comment: Is binding it to the private address not feasible?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's feasible, yes. However, I'd have to change a ton of configuration settings everywhere on Server A since the IP address would be different. Just looking for an easier option. I'd rather have it so connecting to "127.0.0.1:3306" will actually connect to Server B.

Comment: MySQL-proxy might be worth a look, although I've never used it http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/.  From the documentation it seems like exactly what you need...if a bit of overkill

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to <private ip>:3306
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar setup, but slightly more complex.

On my home laptop, I have a `/etc/xinetd.d/mysqlfwd` containing

```
service mysqlfwd
{
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 3307 # could be 3306 as well if ther will never be a MySQL server installed here
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        user            = ports
        server          = /usr/local/bin/ports
        server_args     = -s mysql@<mydomain>
}
```

This `mysql@<mydomain>` denotes the SSH subsystem defined on the server. As `mysql` is not, and does not have, a defined subsystem name, I chose to define one by myself using (the appropriate Convention for Names)[http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4250#section-4.6.1].

The used `/usr/local/bin/ports` is defined as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ssh(*args, **opts):
    import subprocess
    map= { False: 'no', True: 'yes' }
    op = [ "-o%s=%s" % (k, map.get(v, v)) for k, v in opts.iteritems()]
    args = op + list(args)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['ssh'] + args)
    return sp

def ssh_conn(*args, **opts):
    args = ['connect@myservernamehere', '-C' ] + list(args)
    opts2 = dict(ControlPath='/tmp/ssh-%r@%h:%p')
    opts2.update(opts)
    return ssh(*args, **opts2)

def master():
    sp = ssh_conn('-f', 'sleep', '15h', ControlMaster=True)
    sp.wait()

def client(*args):
    sp = ssh_conn(*args, **dict(ControlMaster=False))
    sp.wait()

def main():
    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if not args:
        master()
    else:
        client(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the said server, there is a user named `connect` and, as said, a subsystem called `mysql@<mydomain>` The latter is defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the line

```
Subsystem mysql@<mydomain> /usr/bin/netcat localhost 3306
```

The user `connect` exists just to have a platform to operate on hand has, except accepting my "port forwarding key" via its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, no special features, properties or such.

This way my server can keep its MySQL port private (not accessible from outside), but I have a way to connect it nevertheless.